# flexbox grid system

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="product col-lg-10">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="box col-xs-3">auto</div>
            <div class="box col-xs-3">auto</div>
            <div class="box col-xs-3">auto</div>
            <div class="box col-xs-3">auto</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="box col-xs-3">auto</div>
            <div class="box col-xs-3">auto</div>
            <div class="box col-xs-3">auto</div>
            <div class="box col-xs-3">auto</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar col-lg-2">
        <h1>последние новости</h1>
        <input type="text" name="subscribe" class="subscribe" placeholder="почтовый адрес">
        <button class="subscribe">Подписаться</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Не могу понять почему мои боксы стали такие маленькие (были квадратные)`.lg` в `md` в `xs` вставил, но всё же криво всё стало. По правилам flexbox grid всё должно быть вложено в `row` и `col`. В сумме должны составлять сумму 12 вот я попробовал и получилось криво не знаю почему.

**CSS:**

```css
    /* font-family: "LiberationSansRegular"; */
    @font-face {
        font-family: "LiberationSansRegular";
        src: url("../fonts/LiberationSansRegular/LiberationSansRegular.eot");
        src: url("../fonts/LiberationSansRegular/LiberationSansRegular.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("../fonts/LiberationSansRegular/LiberationSansRegular.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../fonts/LiberationSansRegular/LiberationSansRegular.ttf") format("truetype");
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    /* font-family: "LiberationSansBold"; */
    @font-face {
        font-family: "LiberationSansBold";
        src: url("../fonts/LiberationSansBold/LiberationSansBold.eot");
        src: url("../fonts/LiberationSansBold/LiberationSansBold.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("../fonts/LiberationSansBold/LiberationSansBold.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../fonts/LiberationSansBold/LiberationSansBold.ttf") format("truetype");
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    /* font-family: "LiberationSansItalic"; */
    @font-face {
        font-family: "LiberationSansItalic";
        src: url("../fonts/LiberationSansItalic/LiberationSansItalic.eot");
        src: url("../fonts/LiberationSansItalic/LiberationSansItalic.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("../fonts/LiberationSansItalic/LiberationSansItalic.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../fonts/LiberationSansItalic/LiberationSansItalic.ttf") format("truetype");
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    /* font-family: "LiberationSansBoldItalic"; */
    @font-face {
        font-family: "LiberationSansBoldItalic";
        src: url("../fonts/LiberationSansBoldItalic/LiberationSansBoldItalic.eot");
        src: url("../fonts/LiberationSansBoldItalic/LiberationSansBoldItalic.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("../fonts/LiberationSansBoldItalic/LiberationSansBoldItalic.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../fonts/LiberationSansBoldItalic/LiberationSansBoldItalic.ttf") format("truetype");
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: LiberationSansRegular;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }
    
    nav {
      width: 100%;
      height: 53px;
      background: #fefefe;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      font-family: LiberationSansBoldItalic;
    }
    
    .logo {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin-left: 3%;
      float: left;
    }
    
    nav ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    nav > ul > li > a {
        color: #484848;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 17px 37px;
    }
    
    .colomn-cntr {
      width: 50px;
    }
    
    .enter {
      background-image: url(../img/search.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 162px;
      outline: none;
      padding-right: 25px;
      height: 26px;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
    
    .btnEnter {
      border: none;
      background-color: #fff;
      height: 26px;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-family: LiberationSansBoldItalic;
    }
    
    .parallax {
      perspective: 1px;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    
    .hero {
      background: #00f;
      height: 100vh;
      transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    }
    
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    .row {
      background: #fff;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0 6%;
    }
    
    .box {
      margin: 22px;
      background: #cfcfcf;
      height: 207px;
    }
    
    .sidebar {
      height: 270px;
      border: solid 3px #ddd;
      margin-top: 20px; 
    }
    
    .subscribe {
      border: solid #83cdbc 2px;
      background-color: #fff;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    
    .footer {
      height: 480px;
      padding: 0 6%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }
    
    a>img {
      height: 32px;
      width: 32px;
      }
    
    ul>li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Comment: css код добавьте

Comment: Ну и плюс там библиотека flexbox grid

Comment: У вас флексбокс применяется только к `.footer` которого нет в вашем html примере и вообще в css коде много лишнего не по html. Прочитайте [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Это только часть проекта html а вот CSS весь полностью.Я могу скинуть полностью весь проект.